# How do I write a C++ code to record variable location of robot in rosbag file?

Tags: ros, rosbag, rosbag-record

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a code to record in rosbag file. But if the rosbag file starts, then the robot does not move because of sequential way of code.
Here is that part of code :

```
i=system("rosbag record -a");
while(ros::ok())
{   
    //Declares the message to be sent
    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    msg.linear.x=3;
    msg.angular.z=-0.3;
    //Publish the message
    pub.publish(msg);
    //Delays until it is time to send another message   
    rate.sleep();   
}
```

I need to record in rosbag file while simultaneously moving the robot, then after sometime close the file. How to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237611/how-do-i-write-a-c++-code-to-record-variable-location-of-robot-in-rosbag-file?/) by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-21**:
maybe checking out [this discussion](http://answers.ros.org/question/216866/rosbag-record-a-in-c/) helps.

**Comment by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on 2016-06-21**:
I already checked it. It only provides the way to start rosbag file in a code, which I did. I need to simultaneously move the robot and later close the file through code.

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-06-21**:
You can use a service to close the file when you want.

**Comment by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on 2016-06-21**:
Can you explain me on how to use a service? I am unaware of that. Are you talking about something of service-client kind?

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-06-21**:
Yes it's another way to communicate with ROS nodes. Services allow you to communicate with nodes at a given time.

You can look to the ros wiki for more information : http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can create a bag file using rosbag api and write your topics in it .[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API)

---

Originally posted by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) with karma: 70 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0